# Java 8 throws exception where Java 6 does not when executing GET request

Tags: java, http, java-8

I am using simple code to execute get request and load page data. Relevant code is here :

```
public class HttpTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://" + args[0] + "/send?pts=900000000&place=1");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        result.append((char) c);
    }

    String response = result.toString();
    System.out.println(response);
}
}
```

When I execute the code with Java 6 everything is OK and my code prints the response. But when I execute it with Java 8 I get error on opening the stream :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1553)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at HttpTest.main(HttpTest.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I tried different methods and used some libraries but always with Java 8 I get errors.
When curl-ing that URL or testing it with postman I can see that the response does not contain any header fields and statuses but I can not change the service that is giving that response so somehow I must tell Java 8 to chill about missing code 200 and headers and to just give me what is there in the body. How?

Comment: Does it happen with any particular URL or one that's internal?  That is to say, could we reproduce it on our side too?  I wouldn't know what to pass as a command-line argument.

Comment: Do you have intellij properly configured with  Project SDK  1.8?

Comment: @Makoto It is because of that internal service answers to the http get requests with a malformed response without headers and status code (java 8 picks -1 status code) but java 6 chills and gives me the body of the response where java 8 do not. I would like to find a way for java 8 to just read the response as it is ignoring what is proper http response without nagging about it because I can not change that service to responds properly.

Comment: @Opetion Yes, everything is properly configured. I have working projects on both 1.6 and 1.8, but this thing just bothers me for a few hours now.

Comment: ...Again, could *we* also reproduce the error?  It'd make finding the issue easier for all of us.  It's tough to understand the problem if I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: @Makoto I know, but I could not expose this service because it is in my intranet :/ Thank you for your interest but in the mean time I got the answer I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t expect an error tolerance from an `http` client implementation unless explicitly specified. So if you know that the server isn’t actually an `http` server (strictly speaking), you might simply implement a manual socket access mimicking the `http` protocol as far as the server understands. It’s as simple as

```
String host = args[0];
try(Socket s=new Socket(host, 80)) {
    Writer w=new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    w.write("GET http://"+host+"/send?pts=900000000&place=1 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    w.flush();

    // rest taken from your original code, what you are basically doing
    // is interpreting the received data like being ISO_8851_1 encoded

    // you might have to strip off the remains of the return header, if there is one
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream in = s.getInputStream();

    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        result.append((char) c);
    }

    String response = result.toString();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much this works with a minor correction, after GET I removed protocol and host part and it works as such "GET /send?pts=900000000&place=1 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n". On the other, conclusion is that Java 6 handled this badly because it allowed malformed http answers?

Comment: Since neither, reporting protocol errors nor recovering from them, was specified, both behaviors are within the specification. You can always find a use case where either of them would be desired. So you might ask for a configurable option but that’s rather a request for enhancement, not for a bug fix.

Comment: Yup, In my question in this topic I was kind of requesting a hint for configuration option to not throw the exception, but anyway your solution is working and that is what matters so I can move on from this crazy API. (and the last one I had to interact with was putting answers in the header null key, like null=value... that was also interesting to find and handle)